# Which is the best book to learn meta-analysis?

Tags: references, meta-analysis

I have somewhat extensive experience in meta-analysis, but remain an avid reader on this topic.

I am thus wondering, which is the best book to learn meta-analysis in general?

And which books are the best for selected topics, e.g. diagnostic meta-analysis, individual patient data meta-analysis, Bayesian meta-analysis, and network meta-analysis, just to name a few?

This is not a banal question, as a simple [Amazon search](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=meta-analysis) returns more than 900 results.

Interestingly, Amazon suggests as most relevant [Introduction to Meta-Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470057246) by Borenstein and Hedges, whilst the first for feedback is [The Handbook of Research Synthesis and Meta-Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0871541637) by Cooper and Hedges. Google Books instead lists first [Meta-Analysis in Social Research](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014S2I35Y) by Glass, McGaw, and Smith, whereas Google Scholar clearly establishes the [Cochrane Handbook for Systematic Reviews of Interventions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470699515) by Higgins and Green as the most quoted one.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is: *[Introduction to Meta-Analysis](https://smile.amazon.com/Introduction-Meta-Analysis-Michael-Borenstein/dp/0470057246/ref=smi_www_rco2_go_smi_g2609328962?_encoding=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0&ie=UTF8)* 1st Edition
by Michael Borenstein (Author), Larry V. Hedges  (Author), Julian P. T. Higgins (Author), Hannah R. Rothstein (Author). ISBN-13: 978-0470057247

Answer (score 3):

For theory the classic book by Olkin and Hedges is my favorite.  The practical book by Bornstein, Hedges et al. is really a good applied book that introduces and explains their software.

Larry V. Hedges and Ingram Olkin. "Statistical Methods for Meta-Analysis"
Academic Press, 2014

Borenstein, Michael, et al. "Introduction to Meta-Analysis". John Wiley & Sons, Ltd, 2009.

Comment: Giving full bibliographic references would enhance this answer.